# Using Isotope's smartresize() to make divs fluid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I've been stuck for hours on how to implement the [$(window).smartresize()](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/demos/fluid-responsive.html) function to make my divs fluid.

I used the javascript from this[theme](http://themetrust.com/demos/ink/) but when I try to implement it myself, my divs do not resize.

I made a simpler page to try to test it and here it is. I ran Chrome Inspector many times through this and it seems that the width is not changing with the resize. I have a feeling it's because I used :before in the CSS but I'm not sure.

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbs"> 
 <div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x225');"> </div> 
 <div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x225');"></div>
 <div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x225');"> </div>
 <div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x225');"> </div>
 <div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x225');"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
 overflow:hidden;
 width:308px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.item:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 75%;
}
```

**JS**

```
var $gridContainer = $('.thumbs');
var colW;
var thumbWidth = 308;

function isotopeInit() {
 setColumns();  
 $gridContainer.isotope({       
  resizable: false,
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  masonry: {
   columnWidth: colW
  }
 });    
}

function setColumns()
{   
 var columns;
 console.log($gridContainer.width()/thumbWidth);

 columns = Math.ceil($gridContainer.width()/thumbWidth);    
 colW = Math.floor($gridContainer.width() / columns);
 $('.item').each(function(id){
  $(this).css('width',colW-gridGutter+'px');
 });
}

function gridResize() { 
 setColumns();

 $gridContainer.isotope({
  resizable: false,
  masonry: {
   columnWidth: colW
  }
 })     
}

$(window).load(function(){      
 isotopeInit(); 

});

$(window).smartresize(function(){
 gridResize();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smartresize() function was only available with Isotope v1 and I was running v2. In the end, I solved this by using an open source [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize) which  provided the same functions as smartresize() and was compatible with Isotope v2.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the link you provided goes to the Isotope v1 docs and that the `resizable` option you are using is exclusively an Isotope v1 option, I'm assuming you're using Isotope v1.

I would suggest that you update to [Isotope v2](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and use percentage sizing for your Isotope elements and use [element sizing](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#element-sizing) to resize your container and [column widths](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html#columnwidth). This technique is demonstarted in [this](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mIkhq) jsfiddle by David DeSandro, the create of Isotope.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually usually v2 so that was where the problem was.